# How to define a shader in a separate file in Haskell and GPipe

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell (I'm mostly experienced in C++ and Java), so my first attempt is to write a 3D program with GPipe.

Currently, I have the shader defined in the same file as the "main" program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, PackageImports, TypeFamilies #-}
module Drawy (drawyRun) where

import Graphics.GPipe
import qualified "GPipe-GLFW" Graphics.GPipe.Context.GLFW as GLFW
import Control.Monad (unless)

mainShader = do
      primitiveStream <- toPrimitiveStream id
      let tPrimStr = fmap (\(pos,col) -> (pos - V4 1 0 0 0, col  - V3 1 0 0)) primitiveStream
      fragmentStream <- rasterize (const (FrontAndBack, ViewPort (V2 0 0) (V2 500 500), DepthRange 0 1)) tPrimStr
      drawContextColor (const (ContextColorOption NoBlending (V3 True True True))) fragmentStream

drawyRun :: IO ()
drawyRun = do
  runContextT GLFW.newContext (ContextFormatColor RGB8) $ do
    vertexBuffer :: Buffer os (B4 Float, B3 Float) <- newBuffer 3
    writeBuffer vertexBuffer 0 [ (V4 (-1) 1 0 1, V3 1 0 0)
                               , (V4 0 (-1) 0 1, V3 0 1 0)
                               , (V4 1 1 0 1,  V3 0 0 1)
                               ]

    shader <- compileShader mainShader

    loop vertexBuffer shader 0.0

loop vertexBuffer shader i = do

  writeBuffer vertexBuffer 0 [ (V4 (-1) 1 0 1, V3 1 0 1)
                             , (V4 0 (-1) 0 1, V3 0 1 0)
                             , (V4 1 0 0 1,  V3 0 0 1)
                             ]

  render $ do
    clearContextColor (V3 0.0 0.0 0.0)
    vertexArray <- newVertexArray vertexBuffer
    let primitiveArray = toPrimitiveArray TriangleList vertexArray
    shader primitiveArray
  swapContextBuffers

  closeRequested <- GLFW.windowShouldClose
  unless closeRequested $
    loop vertexBuffer shader (i+0.1)
```

However, I'd like to put the shader in a different file like this:

```
module Shaders(mainShader) where

import Graphics.GPipe
import Control.Monad (unless)

mainShader :: Shader
mainShader = do
      primitiveStream <- toPrimitiveStream id
      let tPrimStr = fmap (\(pos,col) -> (pos - V4 1 0 0 0, col  - V3 1 0 0)) primitiveStream
      fragmentStream <- rasterize (const (FrontAndBack, ViewPort (V2 0 0) (V2 500 500), DepthRange 0 1)) tPrimStr
      drawContextColor (const (ContextColorOption NoBlending (V3 True True True))) fragmentStream
```

But then, the compiler complains:

> Shaders.hs:6:15: error:
>       • Expecting four more arguments to ‘Shader’
>         Expected a type, but ‘Shader’ has kind ‘* -> * -> * -> * -> *’
>       • In the type signature:
>           mainShader :: Shader

What's the correct way to define the shader in a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, turns out the definition needed some extra information which GHC was able to glean from the single file, but was unable to retrieve when the shader was in a separate file.

This is how it was supposed to be defined:

```
mainShader :: Shader os (ContextFormat RGBFloat ds) (PrimitiveArray p (B4 Float, B3 Float)) ()
mainShader = do
      primitiveStream <- toPrimitiveStream id
      let tPrimStr = fmap (\(pos,col) -> (pos - V4 1 0 0 0, col  - V3 1 0 0)) primitiveStream
      fragmentStream <- rasterize (const (FrontAndBack, ViewPort (V2 0 0) (V2 500 500), DepthRange 0 1)) tPrimStr
      drawContextColor (const (ContextColorOption NoBlending (V3 True True True))) fragmentStream
```